# Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "TryConvertInt", or the name is ambiguous

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions

I'm calling this scalar-function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TryConvertInt(@Value varchar(200))
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET @Value = REPLACE(@Value, ',', '')

    IF ISNUMERIC(@Value + 'e0') = 0 
       RETURN NULL

    IF (CHARINDEX('.', @Value) > 0 AND CONVERT(bigint, PARSENAME(@Value, 1)) <> 0) 
       RETURN NULL

    DECLARE @I bigint = CASE
                           WHEN CHARINDEX('.', @Value) > 0 
                              THEN CONVERT(bigint, PARSENAME(@Value, 2))
                              ELSE CONVERT(bigint, @Value)
                        END

    IF ABS(@I) > 2147483647 
        RETURN NULL

    RETURN @I
END
GO
```

in this stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectItem]
    @identifier VARCHAR(200)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        tb_Items_Master.item_auto_code AS 'Item Code',
        tb_Items_Master.item_name_en AS 'Item Name',
        MIN(tb_Quantity_Expire.expity_date) AS 'Expiry',
        SUM(tb_Quantity_Expire.quantity) AS 'Stock',
        tb_Items_Master.price AS 'Price'
    FROM
        (tb_Items_Master
    INNER JOIN
        tb_Quantity_Expire ON tb_Items_Master.item_auto_code = tb_Quantity_Expire.item_auto_code
    LEFT JOIN
        tb_Items_Codes ON tb_Items_Master.item_auto_code = tb_Items_Codes.item_auto_code)
    WHERE
        tb_Items_Codes.item_code = @identifier
        OR tb_Items_Master.item_name_en LIKE '%'+@identifier+'%'
        OR tb_Items_Master.item_name_2 LIKE '%'+@identifier+'%'
        -- I'm calling it in the following line
        OR tb_Items_Master.item_auto_code = SELECT dbo.TryConvertInt(@identifier)
    GROUP BY
        tb_Items_Master.item_auto_code, tb_Items_Master.item_name_en,
        tb_Items_Master.price;
END
```

I get the error

> Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "TryConvertInt", or the name is ambiguous

I found similar questions but their answers didn't help, or there is something I'm not aware of

Comment: Remove the word "select". FWIW, scalar functions are notoriously poor performers. Maybe an inline table valued function would be good choice here.

Comment: @SeanLange: function are poor performers mostly when they hide any data access going on. This function is only doing scalar and conversion work on parameters etc. - thus I believe it would perform OK

Comment: @marc_s yes. I didn't look closely at the function since it was just noise to the issue. I agree the performance with such a function is likely a non-issue.

Comment: @Sean Lange: yes, removing "select" solved it..Sorry for this poor value question. Thanks alot

Comment: Glad you got it solved. You might consider just deleting this question as it is basically just a syntax error and not likely to help anybody down the road.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `tb_Items_Master.item_auto_code = select dbo.TryConvertInt(@identifier)`. Unsure if this is a scalar function or a table value function. I assume the former, but I'll post how you reference both:

Scalar function

```
tb_Items_Master.item_auto_code = dbo.TryConvertInt(@identifier)
```

Table Value Function

```
tb_Items_Master.item_auto_code = (SELECT dbo.TryConvertInt(@identifier))
```

Or

```
--In your `FROM` clause
CROSS APPLY dbo.TryConvertInt(@identifier) TCI
WHERE ...
   OR tb_Items_Master.item_auto_code = TCI.[column name] --I don't know what the name of the column returned it
                                                         --So you'll need to amend that
```

That function, however, *implies* from it's name that it's a function that attempts to convert a `varchar` to an `int` and won't fail? There's a function already that does in SQL Server called `TRY_CONVERT`, so you could just do:

```
tb_Items_Master.item_auto_code = TRY_CONVERT(int,@identifier)
```

Comment: @ Larnu: Thanks alot